# I can't use params in @mixin somehow

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to use clamp() with @mixin and I can't use param.. here is my example

```
$a: 1.75rem;
$b: 3vw;
$c: 2.21rem;

@mixin fluid-txt($min-size, $scaler, $max-size){
  font-size: clamp($min-size, $scaler, $max-size);
}

h1 {
  @include fluid-txt($a, $b, $c) <--- this one no work
  @include fluid-txt(1.75rem, 3vw, 2.21rem) <--- this one works
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use params"? Your code works when I try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change this

```
$a: 1.75rem;
$b: 3vw;
$c: 2.21rem;
```

to

```
@a: 1.75rem;
@b: 3vw;
@c: 2.21rem;
```

and this

```
@include fluid-txt($a, $b, $c)
```

to

```
@include fluid-txt(@a, @b, @c)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @5n0wt! I tried your answer and there is syntax error..

Comment: Try this:

@a: 1.75rem;
@b: 3vw;
@c: 2.21rem;

.fluid-txt(@minSize, @scaler, @maxSize) {
  font-size: clamp($minSize, $scaler, $maxSize);
}

h1 {
  .fluidTxt(@a, @b, @c);
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to incapsulate variables in mixin:

```scss
$a: 1.75rem;
$b: 3vw;
$c: 2.21rem;

@mixin fluid-txt($min-size, $scaler, $max-size){
  font-size: clamp(#{$min-size}, #{$scaler}, #{$max-size});
}

h1 {
  @include fluid-txt($a, $b, $c);
  // @include fluid-txt(1.75rem, 3vw, 2.21rem);
}
```

```html
<h1>Test text</h1>
```

[Also, you can take a look in this Codepen.io example.](https://codepen.io/yaroslav-trach/pen/oNoggrz)